# Lists.GetVersionCollection in SharePoint 2010

Tags: web-services

I am trying to pull version history for a specific column in a list and cannot get the syntax for the method correct. I keep getting the error,

> Exception of type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown

I know that the List ID I am using is the correct list ID and I know that my service reference is working properly because I can get data from other methods such as `Lists.GetList(ListName)`.  Any help I can get would be great.  I am trying to get the version history from the first list item from the column called Description.

Here is my call:

```
var descriptionVersionCollection = myList.GetVersionCollection("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx", "1", "_Description");
```

> Exception Detail: System.ServiceModel.FaultException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2146233087   Message=Exception of type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.
>   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>       Server stack trace: 
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>       Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type).....

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
var descriptionVersionCollection = myList.GetVersionCollection("{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}", "1", "_Description");
```